# Manual function module transport into another system existing function group?

Tags: import, abap, transport, function-module, sap-basis

I need to transport function modules from one SAP system into another, which are not connected to each other. I am using CG3Y/CG3Z to download/upload cofiles and data files. I add the transport to import list in STMS.

There is function group to which transported function modules belong, already created in both origin and destination system. The function group already contains different function modules, so deleting it is not an option. It does not contain function modules I am trying to import.

The transport contains only function modules, not function group. When I try to import this transport, I get an error

`R3TRFUGRZXXX original object cannot be replaced.`

I tried checking the Overwrite Originals, which results in "successful" import, but when I try to access it via SE80, I get an error

`Function group <name> contains errors.`

I tried repairing the function group via SE37, which deleted function modules that were in the function group before import, so I can only see the newly transported FMs.

I am testing this on temporary/test function modules/groups, until I figure out how to do this properly without messing up the real function group.

Is there any way to do the import successfully and keep all the function modules?

Comment: If other people visit this question, I'd like to clarify what you say: 1) "from one SAP system into another": let's call them "S" and "T". 2) "I am using CG3Y/CG3Z... `cofiles` and `data` files": a Transport Request (TR) is made of 2 files which are stored in these 2 directories when a transportable TR is released. 3) "error R3TRFUGRZXXX original object" means that your function group is named ZXXX and its Source System is not "S" as in the TR. Last thing: it seems that you do some tests by maintaining the function group/modules directly in "T", so the import cannot work right. Do you confirm?

Comment: @SandraRossi Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAP systems store FM as the program includes, so there is no function module without the group: "each [..] function module in the function group, the system automatically creates an include file and assigns it a name using the following format: `L<FGRP>U<NN>`" [[source]](https://help.sap.com/viewer/bd833c8355f34e96a6e83096b38bf192/latest/en-US/d1801f1c454211d189710000e8322d00.html)

This is why you need to combine all your function modules in one system and one function group. Once you do it, create transport of copies to your destination system and import with the "overwrite originals" option.

To combine your function modules, copy your destination function module to a newly created function group, export the new group, and then import it to the "origin system." and move them manually to the existing group.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, I used it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Maritas.

`R3TRFUGRZXXX original object cannot be replaced.`

This means that the function group object **is**, in fact, included in your transport. `R3TR` `FUGR` (stands for `FU`nction `GR`oup)

A posible solution, is doing a manual merging of the Function Group programs. If we are talking just about 1 FM, then it shouldn't be such a problem for an ABAP dev.

Comment: Hello cape_bsas,

This is what my object list looks like. It might be that SAP puts the function group to transport each time you do a FM transport implicitly.

Object List
       FTBK914652       FISEDC       ISS RoS Test FM
           Object List of Request
               Function Module
                   ZISS_ROS_TEST_FTB_FM. 

It is about 30 FMs and are supposed to go to several systems, so while doable, would be very tedious.

Comment: Now I see the scenario Marita, you are right, that work would be very complicated... I hope someone comes up with an answer